# How to swap the "fn" use of Function keys on an Apple Keyboard in Linux

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, keymap

I have an apple slim keyboard (USB) and if I want to use one of the Function Key as-is, I also have to press "fn " key first. Otherwise, it will try to perform the other function of the key, such as increasing or decreasing the display intensity, change the volume/mute, etc....

As well, the fn key is actually in the position of the "insert" key for regular keyboards. How can I fix all of that ?

I really like this keyboard, as it make my typing much easier, and much more silent too. But some of those mappings that are different sometime bug me.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
echo 0 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
```

Or, in case of permission issue:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
```

This will prevent you from having to reboot. Adding the option is a good idea, so the change persists through reboots.

- 0 = Fn key disabled
- 1 = Fn key pressed by default
- 2 = Fn key released by default

From `/drivers/hid/hid-apple.c` [line 42](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/drivers/hid/hid-apple.c):

> Mode of fn key on Apple keyboards (0 = disabled, [1] = fkeyslast, 2 = fkeysfirst)

Comment: It seems I'm not using an apple driver, so this isn't working for me.  I have an off-brand apple keyboard (Razor Black Widow).

Comment: @Kieveli when people say apple keyboard they don't mean it generically, they mean as in apple hardware. if the hardware is not apple then you won't be using apple's driver. you gotta find out which driver you're first

Comment: For Ubuntu 14.04.3, answer by @cynyr does not works. You get "permission denied". Working one is here: echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode

Comment: for issues with permission, see [http://askubuntu.com/questions/103643/cannot-echo-hello-x-txt-even-with-sudo](here)

Comment: I'm using a KUL ES-87 keyboard which has a hardware OS X Mode switch and this answer works for me.

Comment: After an update in `Ubuntu 20`, my dir `/sys/module/hid_apple` was deleted, how can I restore it?

Comment: This works for me but the preference does not survive reboot (as expected – [`/sys` is a virtual, RAM-based filesystem](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt)). To set the preference permanently, follow [wuputah’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/259340/84807).

Answer (score 42):

The answer above about what option to set in `/etc/modprobe.d` is a bit out of date. Fortunately there is [detailed documentation on the Apple Keyboard support](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard):

> 1. Edit or create the file /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf, e.g.:
>
>    `gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf`
> 2. Add this line to the previously open file.
>
>    `options hid_apple fnmode=2`
> 3. Save the file and execute the following command to notify hid_apple module to reload it's configuration.
>
>    `sudo update-initramfs -u`
> 4. Reboot

I'd personally recommend `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` to update it for all your kernels (once you are confident the setting works as expected).

Setting the fnmode under `/sys` still works the same way:

```
sudo -s 'echo 2 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode'
```

The values in both methods are as follows:

> - 0 = disabled : Disable the 'fn' key. Pressing 'fn'+'F8' will behave like you only press 'F8'
> - 1 = fkeyslast : Function keys are used as last key. Pressing 'F8' key will act as a special key. Pressing 'fn'+'F8' will behave like a F8.
> - 2 = fkeysfirst : Function keys are used as first key. Pressing 'F8' key will behave like a F8. Pressing 'fn'+'F8' will act as special key (play/pause)

Comment: Thanks - I've added this method to my Linux Mint setup scripts at https://github.com/duncan-bayne/mint-setup

Comment: All you need is to run as root (on Fedora distro at least) `echo 2 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode` to make FN as primary and Mac controls secondary. Oh, yeah!! Thanks, wuputah!!

Comment: Bonus: If you want to make your ~ key work, you should also set iso_layout=0. My hid_apple.conf looks like this: options hid_apple fnmode=2 iso_layout=0

Comment: WOW you just made my life soo much better thank you!

Comment: Works in Kubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 6):

From [Here](http://www.rickycampbell.com/swap-fn/)

how do we swap the function of the Fn key?

First edit /etc/modprobe.d/options

> sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/options

and make sure it has the line

> options hid pb_fnmode=2

Then save and exit. Lastly, we need to update ramfs:

> sudo update-initramfs -u -v -k `uname -r`

Then just reboot!

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me on **Fedora 24**

1. Create a new file for SystemD to start.

   `gedit /usr/lib/systemd/system/mac-keyboard.service`

   Ensure the file contains the following

   ```
   [Unit]
    Description=mac-keyboard
   [Service]
    Type=oneshot
    ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo 2 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode"
    ExecStop=/bin/sh -c "echo 1 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode"
    RemainAfterExit=yes
   [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
2. Reload SystemD to read your new file

   `systemctl --system daemon-reload`
3. Start the SystemD service.

   `systemctl start mac-keyboard.service`
4. Enable service to start on boot.

   `systemctl enable mac-keyboard.service`

Reference: https://www.dalemacartney.com/2013/06/14/changing-the-default-function-key-behaviour-in-fedora/

Comment: Thanks!!  I really liked this one!!  It worked for me on Pop! OS

Answer (score 1):

On **Ubuntu 22.04**:

```
echo 1 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/swap_fn_leftctrl
```

Or add this line into */etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf*:

```
options hid_apple swap_fn_leftctrl=1
```