# I would like to change how the FN key affects function keys on Lenovo IdeaPad z500

Tags: windows-8, lenovo-laptop, fn-key

So, the situation is the following. When I press the F1 button (for example), it mutes the notebook and in order to access the function keys I have to press FN.

However, I'm not happy with this so I'd like to change it "back" to how it should work.

There is no corresponding option in the BIOS menu.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Other than some registry tweaks, it [doesn't look promising yet](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/IdeaPad-Y-U-V-Z-and-P-series/Function-keys-on-the-z500/td-p/942015/page/7).  Perhaps someone will come along with specific tweaks/fixes for you.

Comment: Did you really install XP on it?

Comment: I have no idea why windows xp is a tag, I selected windows 8 as one but not xp

Comment: I haven't worked with Lenovo but this will resolve all bloatware issues, clean install windows else if money is an issue clean install Linux. This is what I did because of all thee bloatware on my hp laptop

Answer (score 8):

In my T440 you hold the ESC key while pressing the FN key (called FnLk... function lock) in my unit the tiny green led on the FN key will stay lit.  Acts a little like a Caps Lock.

Comment: Works on the T450 too

Answer (score 1):

Update your BIOS to the latest one which was released by Lenovo on 31 October, 2013. It has enabled support to enable/disable Hotkeys thereby providing you an option to use them as Function keys. Get the BIOS & other updates from http://support.lenovo.com

BTW if you find the updated chipset driver for windows 8.1 for Z500 do post as a reply here. Lenovo has not provided an update for it.

Cheers from a fellow Z500 user !

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone finds this post and has a dell, the option for most of their laptops to toggle the fn key setting is located in the Windows Mobility Center (just do a program search for it in win7/8)

Answer (score 0):

So according to a Lenovo forums post, you can press the Fn key for 20-30 seconds and a menu will pop up asking if you want to revert to the old setup (or legacy mode). If you want to read it for yourself, here's the link: http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-Edge-S-series/Disable-Fn-Keys-E420/td-p/803609. I know that the forum post doesn't exactly refer to your model, but it might work.

If that doesn't work try going to Control Panel -> Keyboard Properties -> ThinkPad F1-F12 Keys. There should be a "use legacy" option.

Comment: That method yields no result on my model sadly but thanks anyway

Comment: Did you see the edit I just made? If so, sorry that it didn't work.

Comment: I don't have that option either

Comment: @UszkarDromar Do you have the Lenovo hotkey drivers installed?

Comment: The z500 is an "[IdeaPad](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/ideapad/z-series/z500-touch/)", not a ThinkPad.

Comment: The z500 is not among the supported models for the hotkey driver

Answer (score -1):

I updated the BIOS to the latest and then followed this article to get into the bios and changed the key settings to Legacy. There's more info [here](http://voyager8.blogspot.com/2014/08/how-to-get-into-bios-setup-utility.html).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.