# How to Logically Swap Fn and CTRL keys in Lenovo E40-80 i5 Laptop?

Tags: keyboard-layout, lenovo-laptop

How to Logically Swap Fn and CTRL keys in Lenovo E40-80 i5 Laptop? As Physical swap is not possible due to key size difference.

I have tried the possible methods like looking at BIOS, as suggested by other forums. But the BIOS in my laptop doesn't have Configuration for Keyboard or anything else.

[image]

Its really frustrating to use such key combination.
Can someone help?

Comment: yes. downloaded the same yesterday

Comment: If there is no BIOS setting, you are likely out of luck, as "Fn is not a normal keyboard key, such as the modifiers Ctrl, Shift and AltGr." Source: http://superuser.com/a/564296/4560