# How to change Fn key to behave like second function

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, fn-key

Fn key on my old computers worked like second function: If I pressed <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>, it inserted a star, <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> inserted 1.

But on my new notebook, the Fn key only works with <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>, which is also <kbd>NumLk</kbd>. If I press this combination, my keyboard is turned permanently to <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys. Therefore I have to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to turn <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys on, then press <kbd>p</kbd> and finally press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> again to turn them off and get classic keyboard layout back in order to write a star. Is there some possibility, how to change this behavior to the first case (just <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> for a star) I've used to use? Is there some setting in Windows?

Comment: There may be a setting in your bios for how the function key behaves. It is not one of the standard keys so unless you can figure out what its key code is you can't remap it to something else and it's unlikely that you'll be able to do that within Windows anyways because Windows doesn't give you that kind of control. I also just realized that you were probably using the onboard numeric keypad when holding down function p period but that may not work if you have an external keyboard attached

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately there was no option to change this behavior in my bios :(

Comment: The Function Key may also not behave as you expect with an external keyboard or mouse attached. The other thing you can look for is if the keys have any writing on them of the same color as the function key writing. That is one way manufacturer indicate valid function use. hth.

Comment: There is some additional information about how the Lenovo Function key behaves here: https://superuser.com/questions/564289/how-to-swap-the-fn-use-of-function-keys-on-a-generic-keyboard-in-linux?noredirect=1&lq=1 and